# Deleting scripts from copied GAS spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

been looking high-and low on this issue and only found an eHow article that said that if I delete the scripts from a project that the scripts will be totally removed from the cloud.

My situation is that I have a spreadsheet which due to the limitations of the permissions features, I have to split into 2 files: one for in-house use and another for public viewing. All the dev work was already done in the in-house master version, so I've simply copied the sheet, renamed it and removed everything not needed from the public copy.

What I need to do is to remove the scripts as well, however I don't want go back to the master and discover that the scripts have disappeared there too.

So are my concerns correct? And if so, how to I remove the scripts from the copy without affecting the master.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the scripts from the copy, the master spreadsheet will not be affected. Go forth and delete the scripts in your copy

Comment: Thanks Srik, glad to hear that! just to be clear, will the scripts be permanently deleted only if I delete them from the master copy? or will the still be floating around the cloud?

Comment: Yes, if you want them permanently deleted, you have to remove them from the master copy as well. However, if your master copy isn't shared with anyone, this will not pose a problem.